# Expanding elliptic function of third kind

Tags: series-expansion

I want to expand an elliptic function of third kind in terms of $g$,
where $n$, $\psi$, and $k$ are functions of $g$.

For example, I defined

```
h = g/(2/3^(1/2) (1 - a0^2 g^2)^(1/2)Cos[1/3 ArcCos[-3 3^(1/2) g (1 - a0 g)^2/(1 - a0^2 g^2)^(3/2)]]);
hsc = (1 + a0/g)/(1 - a0/g);
k = ((((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2) + (6 h)/hsc - 1)/(2 ((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2)))^(1/2);
ψ = ArcSin[((1 - (2 h)/hsc - ((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2))/(1 - (6 h)/hsc - ((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2)))^(1/2)];
n = (1 - (6 h)/hsc - ((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2))/(1 - (2 h)/hsc - ((1 - (2 h)/hsc) (1 + (6 h)/hsc))^(1/2) - 4/(a0^2 hsc) (1 + (1 - a0^2)^(1/2)));
```

but I cannot get the expansion with the code

```
Series[EllipticPi[n,ψ,k],{g,0,3}]
```

Is there any method to improve on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Mathematica is case-sensitive, use `ArcSin[]` and not `arcsin []`. And by the way, welcome to Mma.SE. Please do follow this advice: Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers.

Comment: Your elliptic function is real-valued for small $h<0$ but complex-valued for small $h>0$, so I think the series expansion will be different in the two regions. *Mathematica* doesn't seem capable of doing this expansion. Maybe you could ask at the [math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) to get better answers. Also, maybe some formulas on the [Wolfram functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticPi3/) could be of use. A series expansion in terms of [AppellF1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppellF1.html) is given, which doesn't help at all.

Comment: You might try to understand the behaviour by plotting the expression as a function of `h`.  This suggests that you have a singularity and a discontinuity at `h=0`

Comment: I have corrected the content, and added the complete code.